# Async consumer for Amazon sqs

Tags: java, asynchronous, amazon-sqs, jmstemplate

I am new to working with queues. 
I am able to successfully post messages and receive them synchronously
However, I am now trying to async now.

The reference links provided by sqs suggests using jmsclient wrapper.
And the link also mentions to use it if you already have a code that is integrated to a jms client.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/jmsclient.html#samples

But I am starting afresh
I referred this example to send and recv messages synchronously.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonSimpleQueueService/SimpleQueueServiceSample.java

Can I use the same code but implement it with a message listener?
Any code examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

There's a code sample in the section about [Using JMS with Amazon SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/jmsclient.html#jmsclient-async) of the Amazon SQS Developer Guide that shows how to asynchronously receive messages using JMS.

First you implement the MessageListener interface:

```
class MyListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            // Cast the received message as TextMessage and print the text to screen.
            if (message != null) {
                System.out.println("Received: " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then you set it as the MessageListener for a MessageConsumer:

```
// Create a consumer for the 'TestQueue'.
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

// Instantiate and set the message listener for the consumer.
consumer.setMessageListener(new MyListener());

// Start receiving incoming messages.
connection.start();

// Wait for 1 second. The listener onMessage() method will be invoked when a message is received.
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: where do I get the object `queue` from to pass to the `.createConsumer` method? I use an existing queue, I do not want to create a new queue.

Comment: Does this continuously listen to messages from queue or does it shutdown after 1 minute?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sqslistener` annotation from SpringCloud framework.
If you are developing application with `Spring` and `AWS` and you are not using `Spring Cloud` , it is good time for you to switch.

Here is a sample code to asynchronously receive message from SQS using `sqslistener` annotation. A good thing is you have to almost zero configuration for using this :

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SqsMessageDeletionPolicy;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.example.my.RecoverableException;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomMessageQueue {

    @SqsListener(value = "${build_request_queue.name}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void receive(String message) {
        try {
            // write message processing here
        } catch (RecoverableException e) {
            // handle errors here for which message from queue should not be deleted
            // throwing an exception will make receive method fail and hence message does not get deleted
            throw e;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // suppress exceptions for which message should be deleted.
        }
    }
}
```

The great thing about `sqslistener` annotation is its `deletionPolicy`. So you can decide when a message from SQS gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is old question I will add another solution I use in one of my Python apps. It might give you an idea how to do it in any language.

I have kind of proxy function (listener) which gets triggered by SQS. In this function I have for loop that loops through messages and invokes another Lambda function by executing invoke method of lambda [client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#client). Each message 'knows' function name which should be invoked.

I use this proxy function for all my other functions within the app and triggered by SQS.

This way I can utilise Lambda destinations functionality added recently.

Answer (score 0):

I use aws sdk to connect to SQS

```
AWSCredentials credential = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credential);
AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(
            awsCredentialsProvider).build();

ReceiveMessageRequest messageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl).withWaitTimeSeconds(10)
            .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);;

ReceiveMessageResult queueResult = sqs.receiveMessage(messageRequest);
    List<Message> messages = offerchangenotificationQue.getMessages();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        log.info("Receive message from queue {}", message.getBody());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

SQS stands for "Simple Queue Service." It is meant to be simple, literally. As a result, it does not support some of the niceties of JMS, in particular asynchronous listeners.

I have written a blog post on this topic: http://thedulinreport.com/2015/05/09/guaranteeing-delivery-of-messages-with-aws-sqs/

Basically, what you need to do is write a poller in an infinite loop, but you want to be smart about it -- you don't want to keep polling too much because you are charged per request.

Comment: Thanks I ll check your post. Instead of us polling, I am looking at options to leverage messagelisteners. Any pointers on that would be very useful.

Comment: There is no message listener in the same sense as JMS message listeners in SQS.